# Disable automatic import of apache LogFactory and Log

Tags: java, eclipse, eclim

Using eclim whenever I type `log.` the following packages are automatically imported:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

The following line is also added the start of my class:

```
private static final Log log =
    LogFactory.getLog(ClassName.class);
```

Not sure if this behavior is coming from Eclipse or Eclim. Is it possible to disable this?

Comment: Look at `Window -> Preferences` and search for `templates`, may be it's defined there for Eclim.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be anywhere in Preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of `vim` configuration, I suggest you to read this to solve your issue : http://eclim.org/vim/java/logging.html

In short, you may add

```
let g:EclimLoggingDisabled = 1
```

through `:VimSettings` or to your `.vimrc`.